# unable to create tunnel and connect to jupyter interface

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I am creating an ssh tunnel and configure browser to connect to the notebook interface in google cloud dataproc, I createf tunnel via putty, it works, but when I open url http://clustername-m:port, it is showing taking too long and timeout.

Appreciate help!

Comment: Whats the command you're using to create the cluster? What does timeout mean? a specific HTTP code like 500 or a browser-side connection timeout?

Comment: gcloud dataproc clusters create my-name \
    --project my-project-id \
    --bucket my-bucket-name \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
    --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
    --initialization-actions \
        gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh

Comment: The connection has timed out

The server at xxxxxxxx-m is taking too long to respond.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PuTTY, you'll want to make sure you're correctly setting [dynamic port forwarding](https://www.math.ucla.edu/computing/kb/creating-ssh-proxy-tunnel-putty) in the PuTTY UI if you're intending to use hostnames like that. You might also need to force your browser to do [DNS resolution on the proxy host](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/socks-proxy) with:

```
--host-resolver-rules='MAP * 0.0.0.0, EXCLUDE localhost'
```

Finally, you might find it all easier if you're using Jupyter or Zeppelin to just use [Dataproc Component Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/dataproc-gateways) with [Dataproc Optional Components](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/overview) and then you won't need to setup any SSH tunnel at all to use the UIs. Keep in mind that at the moment, Component Gateway is only in Alpha though so there are likely going to be bugs in terms of reliability.

Comment: "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" ^
    --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:%8123%" ^
    --user-data-dir="%Temp%\%clustername-m%" ^
    --host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0, EXCLUDE localhost"

Comment: also tried:"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" ^
    --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:8123" ^
    --user-data-dir="%Temp%\%clustername-m%" ^
    --host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0, EXCLUDE localhost"